# Prove that $\sum z^n/(1-z^n)$ is holomorphic on the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the series $$f(z)=\sum_{n>1}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$$ converges in the unit disc $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ and defines there a holomorphic function.

Comment: Do you need any help to translate? Puedo ayudar. Podés escribir todo en español y lo traducimos después.

Comment: Pues si, es fácil traducir pero los términos en matemáticas...

Comment: El ejercicio dice: Prueba que esa seri converge a D(0,1) y que su suma es una función holomorfa.

Comment: Que denota $D(0,1)$?

Comment: Es el disco de centro 0 y radio 1, pensaba que esa nomenclatura era internacional...

Comment: Lo que querrás decir entonces es que la serie converge solo en ese dominio, ¿no?

Comment: si claro, eso era lo que quería decir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a disc $D_r=\{|z|\leq r\}$ for $r\in(0,1)$. Then, if $z\in D_r$,
$$|z|^n\leq r^n$$
and
$$1-|z|^n\geq 1-r^n\geq 1-1/2=1/2\;.$$
if $n$ is big enough, depending on $r$, let us say, for $n>N(r)$.Therefore
$$\sum \frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^n}\leq\frac{N(r)}{1-r}+2\sum r^n=\frac{2+N(r)}{1-r}$$
that is, the series converges absolutely, hence uniformly, on $D_r$, for $r\in (1/2, 1)$.
Every compact $K\Subset D(0,1)$ is contained in some $D_r$ with $r\in (1/2,1)$, so we have that the series converges uniformly on every compact set of $D(0,1)$. Then the limit is a holomorphic function on $D(0,1)$.

EDIT: As noted in the comments, $1-|z|^n\geq 1-|z|$, therefore
$$\sum\frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^n}\leq\sum\frac{r^n}{1-r}=\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}\;.$$

Comment: Hm yes, sorry, I was too fast in writing..

Answer (score 4):

The brute force method works: assume $|z|\lt1$, then $\sum\limits_n\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}=\sum\limits_nz^n\sum\limits_kz^{kn}=\sum\limits_n\sigma_1(n)z^n$, where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, converges absolutely since $\sigma_1(n)\leqslant n$ and $\sum\limits_nn|z|^n$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the series converges uniformly on compact sets.  You can use a ratio test.

Comment: thank you but i don't know how...